# Command prompt php

Tags: php, batch-file

I made a .bat script, but when I run it, it doesn't detect the included file in my php script.

.bat

```
"C:\xampp\php\php.exe" -f "D:/Projects/Web projects/done/sticky/test.php"
```

test.php

```
<?php

include 'db.php';

        try {
            //stm
            $STH = $DBH->prepare( "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) values (:user, :pwd, :email)" );
            //bind
            $data = array( 'user' => 'a', 'pwd' =>'b', 'email' => 'c' );
            //exec
            $STH->execute( $data );
        }
        catch( PDOException $e ) {
            file_put_contents( 'PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND );
            die( "db error" );
        }
?>
```

db.php contains my db info, but the script doesn't detect it. Do note that if I run it normally in my browser, it does work.

Comment: What directory are you executing it in? Unless it's the same directory as the db.php file, then it won't find it unless your include statement identifies what directory it should be found in. Try changing it to `include __DIR__ . '/db.php';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Includes in PHP are relative to the current working directory, not the script's location. However, when accessing a PHP file via a webserver the CWD is usually the location of the script.

In your case you either need to change the directory before running the script or change it in your script using `chdir(__DIR__);`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DS);

require_once(ROOT . 'db.php');
```

Comment: Add more defines as needed, for example `define('LIB_PATH', ROOT . 'library' . DS);`